# Migration Of play 2.4 from 2.3:sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying migrate the play version from 2.3 to 2.4.0,I'm facing an error "**sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.**"
I'm using sbt version of 0.13.8.Java version is 8,Can any one suggest me what to do.
 I'll attach the error occurred in console

```
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins dete
cted.
[error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies:
[error]         org.apache.commons:commons-compress
[error]         org.tukaani:xz
[error]         com.google.guava:guava
[error]         com.typesafe:config
[error]         org.slf4j:slf4j-api
[error]         org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni
[error]         com.typesafe:jse_2.10
[error]         com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine
[error]         com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web
[error]         org.javassist:javassist
[error]         org.scala-sbt:launcher-interface
[error]         org.scala-sbt:interface
[error]         org.scala-sbt:io
[error]         org.scala-sbt:collections
[error]         org.scala-sbt:control
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Here is my "build.sbt"

```
import sbtbuildinfo.Plugin._
import com.typesafe.config._
import sbt._
import Keys._
//import dbConfig.driver.api._
import play.Play.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.{SystemV, Upstart}
serverLoading in Debian := SystemV
name    := "vHMS"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
sbtPlugin := true
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  //javaEbean,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  cache,
  specs2 % Test, 
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context-support" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.6.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.6.RELEASE" % "test", 
   "org.json"%"org.json"%"chargebee-1.0", 
    "org.sql2o" % "sql2o" % "1.5.2",
   "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
   "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "org.modelmapper" % "modelmapper" % "0.7.1",
  "com.sun.jersey"% "jersey-client" % "1.17.1",
  "com.sun.jersey"% "jersey-core" % "1.17.1",
  "com.sun.jersey.contribs"% "jersey-multipart" % "1.17.1",  
  "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "2.7.1",
  "aopalliance" % "aopalliance" % "1.0",
  "cglib" % "cglib" % "3.1",  
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.8.1",
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.1",  
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1",
  "commons-dbcp" % "commons-dbcp" % "1.4",
  "net.vz.mongodb.jackson" %% "play-mongo-jackson-mapper" % "1.1.0",
  "org.springframework.retry" % "spring-retry" % "1.1.0.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.amqp" % "spring-amqp" % "1.4.5.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.amqp"  % "spring-rabbit" % "1.4.5.RELEASE",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4",
  "com.google.apis"  % "google-api-services-storage" % "v1-rev20-1.19.0",
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.19.0",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client" % "1.19.0",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson2" % "1.19.0",
  "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client" % "1.19.0",
  "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-java6" % "1.19.0",
  "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.19.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.1.3",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty-util" % "6.1.26",
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.8.3",
  "org.jasypt" % "jasypt-spring31" % "1.9.0",
  "org.jasypt" % "jasypt" % "1.8",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.2",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.5",
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.5.1",
 "com.itextpdf" % "itextpdf" % "5.5.0",
 "com.itextpdf" % "itext-pdfa" % "5.5.0",
 "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports" % "6.0.0",
"net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports-fonts" % "6.0.0",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-digester3" % "3.2",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.9",
"dom4j" % "dom4j" % "1.6.1",
"antlr" % "antlr" % "2.7.6",
 "javax.transaction" % "jta" % "1.1",
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.5.8",
 "javassist" % "javassist" % "3.9.0.GA",
 "tomcat" % "jasper-compiler-jdt" % "5.5.15",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2",
"org.imgscalr" % "imgscalr-lib" % "4.2",
"com.sandinh" %% "play-hikaricp" % "1.7.1",
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0",
 "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.0-2",
 "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1",
 "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.2.26",
 "com.fizzed" %% "fizzed-play-module-sprockets" % "1.2.0"
 //"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1"
 //"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1"
 //"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.175"
)       
buildInfoSettings
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo
buildInfoPackage := "App"
//pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(concat)
//includeFilter in closure := "all.js"
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify,digest,gzip)
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
//Enable eban plugin for 2.4 migration
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)
lazy val execTask = taskKey[Unit]("Execute the build task")
execTask := {
  val file: File = baseDirectory.value / "buildinfo.properties"
  val prop = new java.util.Properties
  def readProp: Int = {  
    prop.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(file))
    prop.getProperty("buildnumber", "0").toInt
  }
  def writeProp(value: Int) {
      prop.setProperty("buildnumber", value.toString)
      prop.store(new java.io.FileOutputStream(file), null)
    }
    val current = if (file.exists) readProp
                  else 0
    writeProp(current + 1)
    current
}
buildInfoKeys += BuildInfoKey(execTask)
version <<= (version) { (v) =>
if (new File("buildinfo.properties").exists()) {
      val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("buildinfo.properties")).resolve()
      lazy val buildnumber = config.getString("buildnumber")
      val buildversion=buildnumber.toInt/3
       v.replace(".0-SNAPSHOT","."+ buildversion)
    } else {
       v.replace(".0-SNAPSHOT", "."+ "0")
    }
}
resolvers += "Jasper OLAP" at "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo/"
//Specs2 was included for 2.4 migration
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Here is my "plugins.sbt"

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"

//jBcrypt repository
resolvers +="jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/" 

//Modelmapper repository
resolvers +="modelmapper Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/" 

resolvers += "jersey repository" at "http://http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/sun/jersey/"

//AOP repository
resolvers +="aspectj Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/" 

//Rabbit MQ dependency jars
resolvers +="amqp Repository" at "https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit/1.4.5.RELEASE"

//google storage repository
//resolvers +="google storage Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/" 

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-fork-run-plugin" % "2.4.0")

resolvers += "Jasper OLAP" at "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo/"

//resolvers += "Edulify Repository" at "https://edulify.github.io/modules/releases/"
resolvers += Resolver.url("Edulify Repository", url("http://edulify.github.io/modules/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "SBT Plugins" at "https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"

// Use the Play2war plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.3-beta3")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.3.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-web" % "1.0.0")

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")

//Ebean dependency for play 2.4
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

//Byte code enhancement for play 2.4
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "0.13.5"
```

Comment: Please post your build.sbt and project/plugins.sbt

Comment: I have added my buid.sbt and plugins.sbt...Please suggest me,if there is any error...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a more recent version of mailer for play 2.4. Just add this line to your build.sbt (instead of your current import):
`"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"`
also note that the name is play-mailer and play-plugins is not needed.
here is the [link](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer)

Comment: Thanks for your reply vizog..I have changed the mailer import in both build.sbt and application.conf..but still I'm having an error "sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected."

Comment: I noticed you have a dependency override for sbt in your plugins.sb: `dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "0.13.5"` what is that for? and I don't see enabling play plugin : `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")` I'm using play 2.4.6 it is compatible with 2.4.0 and has many bug fixes. why not use that? Also use sbt-web plugin version 1.0.2. Let me know if this fixes your problem

Comment: I have enabled plugin for play as :"addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")",in the above code it was commented mistakenly.Can you please send me plugins.sbt and build.sbt which is used in your PLAY 2.4 project..and sorry for making reply in delay vizog..thanks in advance.

Comment: @sabari I hadn't checked page. Hope you have fixed the problem